# Asterisk Realtime not working after MySQL upgrade to 5.7 version

Tags: mysql, asterisk

Asterisk (version 11 & 13) Realtime was working fine with MySQL version 5.5 but when I upgraded MySQL 5.7. It stops working and following errors appeared:

```
ERROR[17524] res_config_mysql.c: MySQL RealTime: Failed to connect database server <database-name> on localhost (err 2003). Check debug for more info.
WARNING[17524] res_config_mysql.c: Table <table-name> not found in database.  This table should exist if you're using realtime.
```

There was no issue in config files, database and table but it happens after MySQL upgraded from 5.5 to 5.7 version.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue or I should downgrade MySQL to previous version?

Comment: Err 2003 says connection failure. Is MySQL actually running and listening on localhost:3306? You can check this with netstat -lna | grep 3306

Comment: Are you sure your database and tables are still there?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your my.ini or my.cnf in [mysqld] section to include
log_warnings=2    will provide the maximum detail on connection failures.

Post into original question content of your present  my.cnf OR my.ini and error log and someone will likely be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, you also may have rebuild asterisk with new mysql-devel.